# includepdf with file that has dots

Tags: pdfpages

I want to merge some pdfs while adding a entry in the table of contents for each of them. I am trying to do this using a script, so I do not want to change any file names. My LaTeX code, simplifying, looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}

\title{Graph Theory}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Basics of Graph Theory}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Basics of Graph Theory}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Spectral Graph Theory 2: Theorems on Matrices. The Laplacian}
\includepdf[pages=-]{"Spectral Graph Theory 2: Theorems on Matrices. The Laplacian"}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Random walks in graphs. The probabilistic method}
\includepdf[pages=-]{"Random walks in graphs. The probabilistic method"}

\end{document}
```

The first case works fine, the next two ones do not, apparently because there is a dot in the file. I have tried many things I found in this page but none of them work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried an additional pair of braces: `\includepdf{{Spectral Graph Theory 2: Theorems on Matrices. The Laplacian}.pdf}`? Also, consider renaming the files, it is bad practice to use filenames as those.

Comment: What is your latex version?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows I'm not allowed to save a file with a colon in the name, and I strongly advise to avoid this if you want your file names to be portable.

Without the colon and *with a current latex* (I have texlive 2019 and `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3`) the following should work. `grffile` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` are no longer needed with this latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Spectral Graph Theory 2 Theorems on Matrices. The Laplacian}
\end{document}
```